# Posting a map to Facebook using Facebook SDK from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting an image to facebook through FBRequestConnection.
How can I post a map to FB by giving a latitude and longitude. (Also attaching some text with this)
Please advise.

```
   if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {


        NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [params setObject:@"Posting from padivattom" forKey:@"message"];
        [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 //showing an alert for failure

             }
             else
             {
                 //showing an alert for success

             }
          }];
```

Comment: You should have a look at open graph: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 0):

I used the method:

```
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:
                                       parameters:
                                          handler:
```

to post message and map to facebook. (Its post to news feed).

But you can try to add to your dictionary: [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/?q=%@,%@",latitude,longitude] forKey:@"link"];

(If it doesn't work, you can find the Feed Dialog sample on facebook developers page).

I hope it helps